# How to create N quantity of vectors OR arrays in one single time?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, initialization

I was wondering if anyone of you know how to created n amount of vectors or arrays in one one single time?

Let's say I need 100 vectors, or 1000, it would be pretty inefficient to do it manually.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: It is unclear what you mean. What would *manually* look like to you?

Comment: One quick and dirty way would be to make an array of vectors. `std::array<std::vector<TYPE>, 1000> bunchOVectors;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that `std::vector<T>` is a template. You can give it a vector as a type parameter, and make a vector of vectors:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> vectorOfEmptyVectors(1000);
```

Now you have 1000 empty vectors, created on a single line.

Note, however, that doing it on a single line does not help efficiency in any way: internally, 1000 vector objects need to be created. Moreover, if you decide a vector of non-empty vectors, say

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> vectorOfVectors(1000, std::vector<int>(300));
```

then 1000 300-element vectors will be created.

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for, I'm sorry if my question wasn't clear before. I needed X amount of vectors independent from each others, in others words not in the same line. Thank you!

Comment: I was wondering, how would you possible handle each one of these?
Lets say I have this code:
 vector <vector<int> > vectorOfVectors(100, vector<int>(10,rand()% 2));
I tried to access it using a normal approach but it doesn't work

Comment: @Side16 The second parameter is not a generator function for the 100 items that gets called for each item, it's a constructor for a single item that gets constructed once, and then copied 100 times. If you would like to init a vector with 100 different vectors, do it in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can always encapsulate those vectors in a vector. Example: Create 1000 int vectors of 100 elements each:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec_container(1000, std::vector<int>(100));
```

Answer (score 0):

A vector of vectors? Say

```
std::vector<std:vector<double>> my_vec (1000, std::vector<double>());
```

It creates a vector of 1000 empty `vectro<double>` vectors.